# exception only when executing within another program

Tags: java, c++, exception

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I did search a while for an answer without finding anything...

I have an external library for C++ (Ball) that I want to use for reading PDB-Files, but I'm much more experienced with Java. So I figured that I could just write a C++-program that reads the information I want and returns a string via cout, and then run this program within a Java program that reads the output and extracts further information from it.

So far, so good...

Individually, run from the command line, the C++-program works perfectly.
And the Java-program definitely runs the program and recieves an output from it... albeit not the desired one:

> FATAL: uncaught exception!
>
> last entry in the exception handler:  exception of type FileNotFound
>   occured in line 312 of /home/.../ball/source/XRAY/crystalInfo.C 
>   error message: the file XRAY/spacegroups-details.dat could not be found

The strange thing is that this file seems to exists in the directory, and that I don't get an exception if I run the program individually...

I tried adding try/catch-blocks in both programs but that was no help at all. 
I wondered if I should alter the source file that throws this exception, but I'm not at all sure how wise it would be to mess around with it.

Does anyone here have an idea what might cause this kind of behaviour?
And would it make sense to edit the source file?

Comment: The error message refers to the .dat file with the relative path of XRAY/spacgroups-details.dat.  Are you sure the working directory of the C++ program is the same when you run it from your Java app as it is when you run it from the command line?

Comment: Also you appear to be on a Unix/Linux system - filenames are case sensitive on these platforms.

Comment: I'm aware of the case sensitivity and that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: Thank you JJF, your comment helped. I CAN run it from the command line (I don't usually do that when working with eclipse) which was good enough as a solution for me.